# How to show a video path in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, video

I need help to show a route where my video is hosted,
To start I am using the laravel-ffmpeg repository

**Controller:**

```
public function store( Post $post, StoreVideoPostRequest $request)
{
    $filename = Str::random(16) . '.' . $request->video->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $save_path = storage_path('app/public').'/posts/id/'.$post->id.'/uploads/videos_private/';
    $public_path = '/posts/id/'.$post->id.'/uploads/videos_private/'.$filename;

    File::makeDirectory($save_path, $mode = 0755, true, true);
    $request->video->storeAs($public_path, $filename);

    $video = $post->videos()->create([
        'disk'          => 'public',
        'original_name' => $request->video->getClientOriginalName(),
        'path'          => $public_path,
        'title'         => $request->title,
    ]);

    ConvertVideoForStreaming::dispatch($video);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard.posts.index')->with('status', 'Success');
}
```

**As you can see the path where the video is saved is : 
'/posts/id/'.$post->id.'/uploads/videos_private/'.$filename;**

**I made a method to show the video path:**

```
 public function videosPostsprivate($id,$video)
{
    return Storage::get(storage_path('app/public').'/posts/id/'.$id.'/uploads/videos_private/'.$video);
}
```

However an error comes out

PD: To show the images I did the same method but use Image::make

```
public function postProfileAvatar($id,$image)
{
    return Image::make(storage_path('app/public').'/posts/id/'.$id.'/uploads/avatar/'.$image)->response();
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/posts/id/{id}/uploads/videos_private/{video}',
    'VideosPostsController@videosPostsprivate'    
    );
```

Any suggestions on how to show me the video?

Comment: do you have the link setup for `public/storage` to point to `storage/app/public`?

Comment: php artisan storage:link